# how to use send() with integers

Tags: c, winapi, winsock

i have the following code :

```
int * buffer;
buffer = (int *) malloc((320*240)*sizeof(int));
```

after populating the `buffer` with data i want to send it using UDP sockets, however it seems that currently my following `send` function sends just 4 byte (of data) and not ((320*240)*sizeof(int)):

```
iError = send(MySock, (char *)(buffer) , sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

i am tried different combinations on the second and third fields of the `send` function but it doesn't work, What is the correct syntax should i use?

BTW i have to define the `buffer` as `int *` since it being used by other library that has to get that as `int *`.

Comment: Read any [C FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760229/stack-pointer-difference-char-pointer-and-array).

Comment: Side note, it seems like a lot of data to transfer in one go over UDP. You know that UDP does not guarantee proper delivery right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in your `send()` call, you specify `sizeof (buffer)`. This is the size of the variable buffer, which is the size of a pointer, which happens to be four bytes on your system. It's **NOT** the size of the block that the pointer points at, that information is not available.

You must specify `320 * 240 * sizeof *buffer` to get the proper size. Of course, even better is to factor this out into a variable:

```
int *buffer;
const size_t buffer_size = 320 * 240 * sizeof *buffer;

if( (buffer = malloc(buffer_size)) != NULL )
{
  /* ... fill buffer ... */
  send(MySock, buffer, buffer_size, 0);
}
```

There's no need to cast, [`malloc()` returns `void *`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169) and `send()` accepts it.

Note that doing very large `send()`s over [UDP might not work, due to IP fragmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712151/udp-ip-fragmentation-and-mtu). It's better to send it using many small datagrams, in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(buffer)` is the size of a pointer type, which is apparently 4 bytes on your system.

Keep track of the length of your buffer (`320 * 240 * sizeof(int)`) and pass that to `send()`.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
send(MySock, (char *)(buffer) , (320*240)*sizeof(int), 0);
```

instead of

```
send(MySock, (char *)(buffer) , sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

`buffer` is a pointer type and the size of a pointer is `4 byte` for your system (for other system it could be 8 bytes (like  64 bits machines)

you have to put the size of allocated memory and not the size of the pointer. The size of allocated memory is not the same of the size of a pointer pointing on

Comment: "...the size of a pointer is 4 byte". Generally speaking, it's not.

Comment: you mean it should be more specific 4 byte for 32 bits systems

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, although 32-bit or 64-bit is irrelevant. The size of a pointer could be 2 bytes on a 32-bit machine, or 6 bytes on a 64-bit machine, as far as you're concerned.

Comment: @netcoder Thanks for the remark and I updated my answer to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line

```
iError = send(MySock, (char *)(buffer) , sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

You are telling send to send the size of the pointer, which is 4 bytes.
you need to give it (320*240)*sizeof(int).